# Ebean update set column null In PlayFramework2.1

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

some code:

```
`public class Test extends Model {
  @Id
  public Integer id;
  public String name;
  public Double roomFee;
}`
```

**inDataBase:`name 'candy' ; id 1; roomFee 200.5`;**

then i want to update roomFee = Null, so from web front params test.name='changeName',test.id=1

when i get the modle(test: test.name = 'changeName',test.id=1; test.roomFee = null),

after excute the test.update()

inDataBase:**`name 'changeName' ; id 1; roomFee 200.5`;**

column roomFee (is null) not update to null

why Ebean not update column (is null)? How to update column = null

Comment: Which version of Play exactly are you using ?

Comment: version : play-2.1.1 ;

Comment: @candy Have you checked the SQL Ebean generates? You should be able to do that adding `db.default.logStatements=true` and `logger.com.jolbox=DEBUG` to `application.conf`. Also check if adding `@Column(nullable=true)` to the field helps...

Comment: @biesior I ran into the same issue. The `update` statement Ebean generates skips updating the `null` column (i.e. those columns aren't mentioned in the update statement at all). In my case, the column is a `bigint` which is also a reference to the `id` column of another table. The situation doesn't change with `nullable = true` in the `@JoinColumn` annotation.